# Handle OAuth2 callback in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build a Spring Boot project with requires being signed into an OAuth2 SSO.
I have the following Maven dependencies:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web
org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client
org.springframework.security:spring-security-config
```

I use `HttpSecurity` to enforce OAuth2 authentication for the app, using the following:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(101)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatcher("/api/auth/oauth2/callback").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
    }

}
```

Now, what this does is: it sees that the user is not logged in, redirects them to the SSO, and after they have signed in it redirects the user back to the `/api/auth/oauth2/callback?code=...&state=...` endpoint. That all works fine. However, I am fairly new to Spring Boot and I don't understand how I persist the fact the user is now authenticated (I know I still need to validate the callback, that's not a problem).

Here is the authentication model that I would like to implement: I want to generate a hash within the callback endpoint, and store that hash in-memory within the app, and as a cookie on the user's browser. Then, in any subsequent requests, the app would read that cookie's value, find the row in the in-memory database with the hash in it and grab the corresponding user data from the  database row.

I have looked *extensively* for a good example of this, however, all of the Spring Boot based OAuth2 examples use Github/Google OAuth and it seems to handle a lot of stuff under the hood (or perhaps I'm not understanding those properly).

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

In case it helps, here is my `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          custom_sso_name:
            clientId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
            clientSecret: SUPER_SECRET
            authorizationGrantType: authorization_code
            redirectUri: https://dev.localhost/api/auth/oauth2/callback
        provider:
          custom_sso_name:
            userInfoUri: https://sso.example.com/nidp/oauth/nam/userinfo
            authorizationUri: https://sso.example.com/nidp/oauth/nam/authz
            tokenUri: https://sso.example.com/nidp/oauth/nam/token
            preferTokenInfo: false
```

Comment: Hi did you find something? I'm having exactly the same problem...

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí I did indeed find a solution to this by using SpringSecurityContext, I will post my solution here when I can find the time, in the meantime, please see this page which helped me with how to set the user as logged on: https://www.baeldung.com/manually-set-user-authentication-spring-security

Comment: OMG I was looking any article about how to mannually log in an user and didn't found anything. Maybe the 'manual' word was the key after all... Thank you!

Comment: Well this doesn't give me the access token or anything so I think I'm going for REST client and Cookies...

Comment: In my situation, I wrote the endpoint which takes in the oauth2 callback and obtains the access token myself -- and the only thing I wanted was to be able to log in the user after that was completed.

Comment: That's exactly what I would like spring to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [Authentication Provider](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider).

When you have set this, you can autowire the custom
AuthenticationProvider and login a user in your controller whith [SecurityContext](https://www.baeldung.com/manually-set-user-authentication-spring-security) like this:

```
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authManager.authenticate(new UserInfo(yourHash, token, expirationDate)));
```

Here, UserInfo is an example class (which extends `AbstractAuthenticationToken`) that can  hold the hash that you want to save, as any other data you may need.

In the example of the above link they use `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, which may me enough to you if you only want to store a hash. If you want to store extra info I would sugest to use a custom `AuthenticationToken` as it is UserInfo:

```
public class UserInfo extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {


    private String hash;
    private String oAuthToken;
    private DateTime expirationTime;

    public UserInfo (String hash, String oAuthToken, DateTime expirationTime){
        super(Collections.emptyList());
        this.hash= hash;
        this.oAuthToken = oAuthToken;
        this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCredentials() {
       if(expirationTime.isAfter(DateTime.now())){
           return oAuthToken;
       } else {
           return null;
       }
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrincipal() {
        return hash;  //Or anything you stored that may be useful for checking the authentication
    }
```

> Then, in any subsequent requests, the app would read that cookie's
> value, find the row in the in-memory database with the hash in it and
> grab the corresponding user data from the database row.

After this authentication is finished, you can customly check authentication in any request:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String profileSettings(Principal principal) {

    if (principal instanceof UserInfo){
        String hash = ((UserInfo) principal).getPrincipal();
       //Now you can use the hash for your custom logic, such like database reading
       return "profileSettings";
    } else {
       return "login";
    }
}
```